# R: Proportional Hazard Assumption in coxme()

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I am running a mixed effects model using the *coxme()* function in R. The model analyzes the event of product success of firms in different countries. 
Fixed effects are for example GDP, population, technology and cultural variables. Random effects are the different countries.

I know that with *coxph()* it is possible to test for proportional hazard using the *cox.zph()* command.

My question: How can I check for proportional hazard with *coxme()*?

Answer (score 2):

Fixed effects in a random-effects `coxme` model can be checked for proportional hazards (PH) with the same `cox.zph()` function used for standard `coxph()` models. According to the manual, the `fit` argument for `cox.zph()` is "the result of fitting a Cox regression model, using the `coxph` or `coxme` functions."

Random effects "are not checked for proportional hazards, rather they are treated as a fixed offset in model."

An example, borrowed from [this Cross-Validated question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/525093/28500):

```
> library(survival)    
> library(coxme)    
> df <- stanford2
> df$cid <- round(df$id / 10) + 1 ## generates some clusters
> fit <- coxme(Surv(time, status) ~ age + t5 + (1 | cid),data=df)
> fit
Cox mixed-effects model fit by maximum likelihood
  Data: df
  events, n = 102, 157 (27 observations deleted due to missingness)
  Iterations= 2 12 
                    NULL Integrated    Fitted
Log-likelihood -451.0944  -446.8618 -446.8261

                  Chisq   df        p  AIC   BIC
Integrated loglik  8.47 3.00 0.037317 2.47 -5.41
 Penalized loglik  8.54 2.04 0.014582 4.46 -0.88

Model:  Surv(time, status) ~ age + t5 + (1 | cid) 
Fixed coefficients
          coef exp(coef)   se(coef)    z      p
age 0.02960206  1.030045 0.01135724 2.61 0.0091
t5  0.17056610  1.185976 0.18330590 0.93 0.3500

Random effects
 Group Variable  Std Dev      Variance    
 cid   Intercept 0.0199835996 0.0003993443
> cox.zph(fit)
       chisq   df    p
age    0.831 3.00 0.84
t5     2.062 2.04 0.36
GLOBAL 2.767 5.04 0.74
```

This was done with `survival_3.1-11` and `coxme_2.2-16`.