# coxme proportional hazard assumption

Tags: r, cox-regression, hazard

I am running mixed effect Cox models using the coxme function {coxme} in R, and I would like to check the assumption of proportional hazard.

I know that the PH assumption can be verified with the cox.zph function {survival} on cox.ph model.

However, I cannot find the equivalent for coxme models.

In 2015 a similar question has been posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32401706/r-proportional-hazard-assumption-in-coxme), but had no answer.

my questions are:
1) how to test PH assumption on mixed effect cox model coxme?
2) if there is no equivalent of the cox.zph for coxme models, is it valid for publication in scientific article to run mixed effect coxme model but test the PH assumption on a cox.ph model identical to the coxme model but without random effect?

Thanks in advance for your answers.
Regards

Comment: 1) I think this question would be better suited at Cross Validated.

Comment: 2) The easiest way is to transform the data into count process format (see e.g. `survival::survSplit` and add an interaction between the variable for which you want to test the PH assumption and a transformation of the time-variable itself (e.g. x*log(t)) into your model. See here: https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v061c01/v61c01.pdf

Comment: 3) You can include frailty terms in the `coxph` call using `frailty` terms. See examples in `?survival::frailty`. I think you should be able to use the cox.zph function on the objects returned from `coxph` function with frailty terms.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I will read about this transformation process and the frailty terms in cox.ph! However, my reviewers suggested me to use the coxme package to rerun my analyses that is why I need a solution to test the proportional hazard assumption on coxme models.

Comment: Terry Thereau is generally very helpful on such topics. Have you tried emailing him?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `frailty` option in `coxph` function. Let's say, your random effect variable is `B`, your fixed effect variable is `A`. Then you fit your model as below

```
myfit <- coxph( Surv(Time, Censor) ~ A + frailty(B) , data = mydata )
```

Now, you can use `cox.zph(myfit)` to test the proportional hazard assumption.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, but I don't think using the `frailty` option in the `coxph` function will work. In the `cox.zph` documentation, it says:

> Random effects terms such a **frailty or random effects in a coxme model are not checked for proportional hazards**, rather they are treated as a fixed offset in model.

Thus, it's not taking the random effects into account when testing the proportional hazards assumption.